# rails error added to object but not raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing an update of a form. I can't add my validation in my model for x reason, so I'm adding an error in my `projects_controller` in the method `update`. When I update it should raise the error and `render :edit` but it doesn't. Here is my method

```
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  #stuff to update

  #add error if no legal_media checked, unless if creative upload its own conditions
  unless has_media?(@project.legal_option.authorized_format)
    @project.legal_option.authorized_format.errors[:base] << "error message"
  end

  if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
     redirect_to brief_path(@project.order.brief)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

the method `has_media?` returns `false` dans when I type `@project.legal_option.authorized_format.errors[:base]`I have my error message `["error message"]`. 
But when I type `@project.legal_option.authorized_format.valid?`, it returns `true`

Any idea how I could make my method raise this error? 
Thank you!

**UPDATE trying to do the validation in the model** :

Since the beginning I want to check that if my column `custom_document` in `legal_option` isn't `nil` (therefore the user uploaded it in the `update` method of the projects_controller), then, check if there is at least one media in `legal_media`.

Here are my models :

```
class LegalOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_one :authorized_format, class_name: "LegalMedia", foreign_key: "legal_option_id"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authorized_format

  has_attached_file :custom_document
  validates_attachment :custom_document, content_type: { content_type: "application/pdf" }

end



class LegalMedia < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :legal_option

  def self.formats
      {all_media: "Tous Media", internet: "Internet", paper: "Presse papier", object: "Objets", television: "TV", radio: "Radio", cinema: "Cinéma", poster_campaign: "Affiches", :press_relation => "Relations Presse", :plv => "Publicité sur lieux de vente", :event => 'Evènementiel'}
  end

end
```

When I did the validation in the beginning with a `validate :has_media?` My LegalOption.LegalMedia because `legal_option_id` is `nil` in `legal_media`

Answer (score 0):

in the `unless` block, put the line:

`render :edit and return`

like:

```
  unless has_media?(@project.legal_option.authorized_format)
    @project.legal_option.authorized_format.errors[:base] << "error message"
    render :edit and return
  end
```

Comment: Adding to your answer, the `return` is required for it to stop the execution

Answer (score 0):

You should add a validation to the model in order for the `valid?` to do what you are looking for it to do.

If you look at the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F), you'll see that `valid?` just runs all the validations. It doesn't check for any errors that you manually add to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Rails convention dictates that validations shouldn't be implemented in the controller but rather in the model. More specifically, `update_attributes` just runs `valid?` after assigning the attributes, which itself just runs validations defined on the model. Any errors already on the model are cleared out beforehand.

If you re-write this as a custom validation on the model, `update_attributes` should behave as you expect:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :legal_option_has_media
  private
  def legal_option_has_media
    unless has_media? legal_option.authorized_format
      errors.add :base, "error message"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I wanted to do it in the model in the beginning but here is the problem:
 
I have the model `LegalMedia` (it's renamed `authorized_format`) which has a `belongs_to` association with `LegalOption`.
I want to validate the fact that if the column `custom_document` of `legal_option` is `nil`, then `validate :has_media?`. 

But as `legal_option_id` in the `legal_media` object is `nil` (because instance not yet created in edit method), I can't do `legal_option.authorized_format` (which is the same as `legal_option.legal_media`)

Comment: Even if the associations aren't persisted, they should still be accessible if assigned. Are you saying that `legal_option` is `nil` in a custom validation? or what error are you getting in particular? If `legal_option.authorized_format` is the same as `legal_option.legal_media`, how is method `authorized_format` defined? Perhaps you could add your custom validation code to the question...

Comment: Thanks for your help, checkout the **update** part in my question.